# Administrator of Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I'm a administrator in Active Directory but can't modify another administrator account. I can modify other user accounts. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You're likely not an administrator (I.e, a member of Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins or Builtin\Administrators), but have been delegated certain administrative rights. What you're running into is the Security Descriptor Propogator, detailed here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22331.adminsdholder-protected-groups-and-security-descriptor-propagator.aspx